# Interpretted Scripts: Implicit vs Explicit Execution

Tags: interpreted-language

In [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/163766/executing-php-script-from-command-line) I was advised that it is better to execute scripts written in an interpretted language (php, python, etc) by explicitly executing the interpretter and providing the script as an argument, like:

`> php script.php`

rather than adding a line to the script to tell the OS to execute it, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

Why is this true? My intuition tells me that it's safer, in case the script is moved to a system in which the interpreter's executable is located at a different path, but is that the only reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portability is enhanced if you use this idiom:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

but it has drawbacks of its own; see a longer discussion at http://sites.google.com/site/frankpzh/knowledge-library/shebang

Answer (score 0):

Different paths would be the primary reason, especially when binaries start getting stored in x64-denoted paths or installed in /usr/local/bin/php.